# how to get "my pull requests" from github api?

Tags: github-api

If you look at: http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/ it shows you how to get pull requests for a given repository.

How do we get "my pull requests" from the GitHub API similar to the data displayed on the GitHub dashboard?

[image: I need something like this]

Comment: Do you want to get a list programmatically (as the "api" word in the title suggests) or open a view in the browser (as the image suggests)?

Comment: @EmilLundberg the image suggests he took that himself and so I suspect the question is obviously about how he might do so programmatically. :)

Comment: @sigmavirus24 I don't follow... :o ...D'oh, perhaps I should've followed the link, that makes it quite clear. xD

Comment: No worries @EmilLundberg I read it twice just to be certain of what he was asking. I shouldn't have sounded so nonchalant.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 Ah, of course, now I get what you mean! Guess I had my "skeptical/off-topic?" glasses on since I was on a little border patrol through newest at the time. :)

Comment: I edited the question to help clarify

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I asked Github directly. A rep told me to use the search endpoint. Search for issues owned by you that are open and of type `pr`.

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=state%3Aopen+author%3Adavidxia+type%3Apr

If you're using a python client lib like [Pygithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub) you can do

```
issues = gh.search_issues('', state='open', author='davidxia', type='pr')
```

Comment: ahhhh i like that better

Comment: It works, but it's not that intuitive. It should be more straight forward than this, but I guess once you know it...

Comment: By default it only shows first 30 results. But you can browse the others using `per_page` (max 100) and `page` query parameters. For example, https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=author%3Adavidxia+type%3Apr&per_page=70&page=2

Answer (score 14):

You can also use [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) to get all your pull requests :

```graphql
{
  user(login: "bertrandmartel") {
    pullRequests(first: 100, states: OPEN) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        createdAt
        number
        title
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20user(login%3A%20%22bertrandmartel%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pullRequests(first%3A%20100%2C%20states%3A%20OPEN)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createdAt%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20number%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20pageInfo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hasNextPage%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20endCursor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

or using `viewer` :

```graphql
{
  viewer {
    pullRequests(first: 100, states: OPEN) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        createdAt
        number
        title
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to add that the v4 API utilises the Relay spec, so you can do `{ viewer { } }` instead of `{ user(login: "...") }` to get the pullrequests of the currently auth-ed user.

Answer (score 10):

First you have to realize that you must authenticate using either Basic Authentication or a token. Next you have to realize that there is no simple way to do this so you will have to be clever.

To be specific, if you probe `https://api.github.com/issues`, you'll notice that the issues there have a hash called `pull_request` which should have 3 URLs: html, diff, and patch. All three will be non-null if the issue is also a Pull Request. (Pro-tip: They're the same thing as far as GitHub is concerned…sort of.)

If you iterate over your issues and filter for ones where those attributes are not null, then you'll have your pull requests.

Comment: OK So when I ran https://api.github.com/issues on my profile, I got nothing in there. However, I've done pull requests before on the account i was logged in as. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you try `curl -u nddipiazza https://api.github.com/issues` and tell me what you see after typing in your GitHub password? Also what language/framework/wrapper are you using to communicate with the API?

Comment: It gives me a `[]` - what does that mean? (besides the obvious, that i don't have any issues)

Comment: It means you're authenticating properly and as far as GitHub is concerned you have no issues. I'm out of my depth at this point frankly. You might be better off contacting GitHub Support. Be sure to put API in the title so it goes right to their API team.

Comment: I believe OP wants all PRs he **created** when he wrote "my pull requests." I don't think `/issues` or `/user/issues` does this. According to github.com API docs https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.8/v3/issues/#list-issues, these "List all issues **assigned** ... to the authenticated user" not created.

Comment: Is there no way to do this besides listing all my repos, getting the upstream owner for each, listing all upstream repos' PRs, and filtering down to my PRs?! There's a github graphql https://developer.github.com/early-access/graphql/. But it's closed alpha and not sure if this is available for Github Enterprise yet.