# How can I use the github API to get a list of projects that a specific user made a pull request to?

Tags: git, github, github-api

In addition to getting the repository I have to get the merged pull requests and pull out information about the repository itself and about the pull request comments.
I read the sections I needed in the documentation and realized that there is no direct solution for this task. In my implementation:

1. I first get the user's repositories
2. Then I get pull requests to each individual repository /repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls
3. If there are pull requests, then I parse them and upload the information I need

I have seen a solution for finding all pull requests through issues [how to get "my pull requests" from github api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412809/how-to-get-my-pull-requests-from-github-api)

Can I solve this problem easier? Maybe I didn't see some important things in the documentation. Or can I use some library for this?

Comment: This is a PITA with the old API but much easier with graphql. You might find this useful- https://gist.github.com/MichaelCurrin/f8a7a11451ce4ec055d41000c915b595

Comment: @RobertHafner It is very interesting why there is no such convenient method for getting pull requests in REST. Thank you very much. So far, everything works as it should and through fewer actions.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the *GitLab* documentation to explore more:

Link --- *https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html*

Now to answer your question:
Paste this in the command into your terminal

**1.To get all the user in your GitLab as Admin:**

curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:[PASTE YOUR TOKEN]"   *"https://{yourcompanyurl}/api/v4/groups/:id/members/all/:user_id"*

**2.To get list of project a specific user made a pull request to:**

GET *{yourcompanyurl}/pull_requests?author_id=5* --- if you know the user's id | you can get from the previous curl

GET *{yourcompanyurl}/pull_requests?author_username=gitlab-bot* --- if you know the user's name | you can get from the previous curl