# Github api know all the pull requests still open for a user

Tags: github, github-api

I am looking in the documentation but I cannot find the call that allows me through authenticated user, to know all his requests for pull requests still open.

I found this but it doesn't seem very intuitive and easy to use:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43807803/8024296

Someone can help me out.

P.s.

It would also be useful to know the issues still open.

Comment: The suggestion on the post you shared seems to work. I tested with my github username and it returned all my opened `Pull Requests` (https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=state%3Aopen+author%3AGuillaumeFalourd+type%3Apr) or all my opened `Issues` (https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=state%3Aopen+author%3AGuillaumeFalourd+type%3Aissue). Therefore, you can consume those services using a GET request and extract the response as a JSON for field manipulation (it doesn't seem to need authentication to work, therefore it might only return information from public repositories).

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, there is no direct API to get open pull requests of a particular user.

You can use this GitHub public API to get all the open pull request of a particular repository and then from the result you can traverse and filter particular user based upon user_id.

[GetPullrequestAPI](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-pull-requests)

Tip: Make sure to include per_page parameter in the API since by default the API list only 30 pull requests.